# Select-Object -First affects prior cmdlet in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, select-object

The PowerShell [`Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7) that cmdlets should [Implement for the Middle of a Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline) but I suspect that isn't doable for a parameter as `-Last` for the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7). Simply because you can't determine the last entry upfront. In other words: you will need to wait for the input stream to finish until you define the last entry.
To prove this, I wrote a little script:

```
$Data = 1..5 | ForEach-Object {[pscustomobject]@{Index = "$_"}}

$Data | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'Before' $_.Index; $_ } |
Select-Object -Last 5 | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'After' $_.Index }
```

and compared this to `Select-Object *`:

```
$Data | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'Before' $_.Index; $_ } |
Select-Object * | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'After' $_.Index }
```

With results (right: `Select-Object -Last 5`, left: `Select-Object *`):

```
-Last 5  *
-------  -
Before 1 Before 1
Before 2 After 1
Before 3 Before 2
Before 4 After 2
Before 5 Before 3
After 1  After 3
After 2  Before 4
After 3  After 4
After 4  Before 5
After 5  After 5
```

Despite this isn't documented I think that I can conclude from this that the `-Last` parameter indeed chokes the pipeline.
This is not a big deal, but I also tested it against the `-First` parameter and got some disturbing results. To better show this, I am not selecting all the objects but just the **`-First 2**`:

```
$Data | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'Before' $_.Index; $_ } |
Select-Object -First 2 | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'After' $_.Index }

Before 1
After 1
Before 2
After 2
```

Note that with the `-First 2`  parameter not only the following cmdlet shows two objects but **also the preceding cmdlet (`ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'Before' $_.Index; $_ }`) shows only 2 objects (instead of 5)**.

Apparently, the `-First` parameter references directly into the object of the prior cmdlet which is different then e.g. using the **`-Last 2`** parameter:

```
$Data | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'Before' $_.Index; $_ } |
Select-Object -Last 2 | ForEach-Object { Write-Host 'After' $_.Index }

Before 1
Before 2
Before 3
Before 4
Before 5
After 4
After 5
```

This also happens when using the [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host?view=powershell-7) instead of the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7) cmdlet or sending the results to a variable, like:

```
$Before = ""; $After = ""
$Data | ForEach-Object { $Before += $_.Index; $_ } | Select-Object -First 2 | ForEach-Object { $After += $_.Index }
$Before
$After
```

This shows on both Windows Powershell (`5.1.18362.628`) and PowerShell Core (`7.0.0`).
Is this a bug?

Comment: `Sort-Object`, `Group-Object`, and `Select-Object` [with one of the "need them all" parameters] _require the previous that the pipeline stage send "the are no more items" before they will do the required thing. it's logical ... and i thot it was documented, but i cannot find such at this time.

Comment: "Is this a bug?" - is _what_ a bug? You've described some observed behavior, and you seem perfectly capable of reasoning about _why_, but I don't see anything... broken?

Comment: @Mathias, sorry that wasn't very clear, but the issue with '-First 2` is that **the preceding cmdlet also shows  2 objects** and not the initial 5 (I have added this to the question).

Comment: @iRon Ahh, gotcha! There's a good explanation for that!

Comment: Select-object doesn't block, but format-table in the background blocks.  I like the feature that select-object -first kills the pipeline.  It makes sense that select-object -last would block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `Select-Object` affects the upstream commands by *cheating*

That might sound like a joke, but it's not.

To optimize pipeline streaming performance, `Select-Object` uses a trick not available to a regular user developing a `Cmdlet` - it throws a [`StopUpstreamCommandsException`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a34d0f3e808659b0c07b8fdac83aaae1dae43c21/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/parserutils.cs#L186-L194).

Once caught, the runtime (indirectly) calls [`StopProcessing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.stopprocessing) on all the preceding commands, but does *not* treat it as a terminating error event, allowing the downstream cmdlets to continue executing.

This is extremely useful when you have slow or computationally heavy command early in a pipeline:

```
# this will only take ~3 seconds to return with the StopUpstreamCommand behavior
# but would have incurred 8 extra seconds of "waiting to discard" otherwise
Measure-Command {
  1..5 |ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; $_ } |Select-Object -First 3
}
```

Comment: And if for some reason you would like it to still process all of the pipeline objects even though it won't output some of them, you can add the `-Wait` parameter to `Select-Object`. This also obviously prevents the `StopUpstreamCommandsException` from being thrown.