# make get-Childitem stop if a file is found

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, get-childitem

I'm having this code:

```
    $Paths = 'C:\' , 'P:\' , "\\fril01\ufr$\$env:username"

    $torEXE = Get-childitem -path $paths -recurse -Exclude $ExcludePaths -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'  | where-object {$_.name -eq "Tor.exe"}

    if ($torEXE.Exists) {$answer = 1}
```

To check for file tor.exe, but as you can see this check could take some time. the could be a chance the check will find tor.exe on the first few seconds but will continue checkink all the paths. i want it to halt immidietly after it found tor.exe and not continue searching for it.
how can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick `|Select-Object -First $N` at the end of your pipeline to [make it stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790273/select-object-first-affects-prior-cmdlet-in-the-pipeline) after the first `$N` objects reaches `Select-Object`:

```
$torEXE = Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Recurse -Exclude $ExcludePaths -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue'  | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Tor.exe"} |Select -First 1
```

Comment: it will still go throu allllll the folders (even after it finds the file) and in the end it will pipe only the first finding

Comment: It will not, `Select-Object -First 1` will [cause the pipeline to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790273/select-object-first-affects-prior-cmdlet-in-the-pipeline) abruptly after the first `tor.exe` is found, thanks to [the nature of pipeline command processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522415/are-the-cmdlets-in-a-pipeline-executing-in-parallel) in PowerShell

Comment: Thank you so much :)