# Why does piping an external application to Select-Object -First 1 set $LastExitCode to -1?

Tags: powershell, executable, exit-code

I am trying to determine the path to the executable of `git`. Since there might be multiple executables found via `PATH` directories, I want to restrict the result to one path.

When using the following construct, PowerShell sets `$LastExitCode` to `-1`, although an executable was found.

```
$git_path = "$(where.exe git | select-object -first 1)"
```

I am wondering why this exit code is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select -First <int>` works by collecting the requisite amount of input (in your case just 1 string) - after which point it [throws a special exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790273/select-object-first-affects-prior-cmdlet-in-the-pipeline/60791320#60791320) that forces the runtime to interrupt/stop all upstream commands - in the case of an external application like `where.exe`, that means forcefully closing it.

So `-1` is not a real exit code, it's simply the "unknown exit code" value PowerShell uses to indicate that "we'll never know, because I killed'em".